# Error:no such table: When Inserting Data in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert data into `sqlite Database`. I am following `Youtube` Tutorial to do this task.

I have written the following code and it successfully creates `Sqlite Database file` but when i try to insert data it gives me error messages.

I have written the following code. Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="ep";  
    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "transactionsHistory";
    public static final String ID= "ID";
    public static final String MESSAGE= "MESSAGE";
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE= "create table "+ TABLE_NAME + " ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, "+MESSAGE+" TEXT)";
    public static final String DROP_TABLE= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME; 
    private Context context;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null , 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.context= context; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {                  
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
  }

public void insertData(DatabaseHelper dbHelper , String Message){

    SQLiteDatabase db= dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MESSAGE, Message);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    Log.d("Insert Successfull ", "Value : "+Message + " :Data Inserted");
}
```

**Calling DB Class in Activity**

```
public class SuccessActivity extends Activity {

    TextView successMessage;
    String failureMessage;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_success);

        myDb= new DatabaseHelper(this);

        myDb.insertData(myDb, "This is a Random Message ");
```

**Error**

```
08-11 13:16:46.883: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(22338): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: transactionsHistory, db=/data/data/com.example.ep/databases/ep
08-11 13:16:46.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(22338): Error inserting MESSAGE=This is a Random Message 
08-11 13:16:46.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(22338): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: transactionsHistory: , while compiling: INSERT INTO transactionsHistory(MESSAGE) VALUES (?)
08-11 13:16:46.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(22338):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-11 13:16:46.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(22338):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
```

Comment: I think you have changed your table name and have not uninstall the app before running again.Uninstall the app & run again.See if this helps you.

Comment: Why is it `myDb.insertData(myDb, ...`? Copy paste error?

Comment: I deleted the `sqlite database ` file from `DDBMS`  and restart the application..but the issue is still persist

Comment: it is `myDb.insertData(myDb, "This is a Random Message ");`

Comment: Why does it need that parameter? Also, you might want to show the implementation of that method since the error happens there...

Comment: I have updated my question, there is an `insertMethod()` which i call from from `SuccessActivity` to insert the data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table is not being created because you have an error in your `create table` statement. There should be no space between `AUTO` and `INCREMENT` - i.e. it should be:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE= "create table "+ TABLE_NAME + " ( "+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+MESSAGE+" TEXT)";
```

Comment: Thank You so Much !! I was seeing all the questions related to this on `stackoverflow`, many of them contains `Syntax Error` and i  was like how they can be so blind >< - same story continues ...

Comment: Glad to help. Making tiny errors like this is very easily done and sometimes you overlook the obvious expecting the problem to be far more complicated than it really is! Please accept the answer if you're happy it solves the problem.